# How to hide iframe of a embed file from Google Drive folder, if I don't have permission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-drive-shared-drive

Is there any way not to display `iframe`, if I don't have permission for embedded file?

My issue is that I am embedding files from different `Gdrive` folders, not all users have permission to all of them.

So instead of `You don't have permission message` I would like to `hide iframe completely`, because I set `with=100% and height=800px`, so there is unused space in this case. Or `maybe set height=0px` or something.

I was trying to find some jquery solution to check this message, but I `failed`.

```
$("iframe:contains(You need permission)").remove();
```

Also I need to **hide iframe** if there is **nothing** in the frame.

Thank you

Comment: you can not access the content of an iframe, so you can not detect what is in there

Answer (score 1):

You can't access to the iframe content because of [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)  .

But you could call the file from backend with a GET request and perform a check there. Or you could use the [API](https://developers.google.com/drive/). Then you show or not the iframe depending on the result. You could ask about [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions)  like this:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions/permissionId
```